# When I see linking errors, I see strangely formed symbols. Is there any way to analyze them so I can understand my error?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

```
duplicate symbol __ZlsRNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERK6b2Vec2 in:
```

I can see basic_ostream, char_traits and Vec2. What is the cryptic text in between ? Are those base64 id of some sort ?

It might really help to pinpoint what I did wrong in my code to understand this.

Using XCode 5.

Comment: Those are [mangled names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) generated by the compiler. They are [compiler specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a C++ mangled symbol and allows method overloading by generating a different symbol for different method semantics.

It translates to:

```
_operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, b2Vec2 const&)
```

Courtesy of [demangler.com](http://demangler.com/).

Comment: Otherwise, in a shell, you should have the `c++filt` utility; `c++filt <some-input>` will try to demangle each and every token (separated by blanks), and echo either the demangled token or the mangled one (if demangling did not work). Pretty useful to convert the output of a tool where some mangled names appear in the midst of the text... or just to demangle one token.

Comment: woa that's really helping me a lot, I just realized something thanks to it. Thanks ! Still gotta wonder why doesn't clang or other compiler unmangle those.

Comment: @jokoon That's because it's the linker and not the (C++) compiler and the linker can be used to link object files/library from different languages, and it doesn't know those symbols are special.

Comment: Kind of a cop-out that the linker can't produce the demangled output. Surely the linker has to know the language ABI to link and that should be enough to know what language to demangle. This isn't 1990, surely we have progressed.